# CSS not loading in Jira server report

Tags: css, jira, jira-plugin

I am developing a jira server report and I am not able to load my css file.

In my atlassian-plugin.xml I define my web-resource like this:

```
<web-resource key="jira-reports-resources" name="wl-jira-report-plugin Web Resources">
    <dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs</dependency>
    <resource type="download" name="jira-report-plugin.css" location="/css/jira-report-plugin.css"/>
    <resource type="download" name="jira-report-plugin.js" location="/js/jira-report-plugin.js"/>
    <resource type="download" name="images/" location="/images"/>
    <context>jira-reports-context</context>
</web-resource>
```

and my report like this:

```
    <report name="Massnahmen Verantwortlichkeit Report" i18n-name-key="report.massnahme.name"
        key="massnahme-report" class="com.example.reports.massnahme.MassnahmeReport">
    <description key="report.massnahme.description"></description>
    <resource name="view" type="velocity" location="/templates/reports/massnahme/view.vm"/>
    <resource name="i18n" type="i18n" location="report-massnahme"/>
    <label key="report.massnahme.label"></label>
    <!-- the properties of this report which the user must select before running it -->
    <properties>
        <property>
            <key>departmentLeaderId</key>
            <name>report.massnahme.input.user.name</name>
            <description>report.massnahme.input.user.description</description>
            <type>multiselect</type>
            <values class="com.example.reports.massnahme.generator.MassnahmeUserGenerator"/>
        </property>
    </properties>
</report>
```

In my report java class I add the WebResourceManager into the velocityParams and in my view.vm I call it in the first row:

```
$webResourceManager.requireResourcesForContext("jira-reports-context")
```

In my view.vm I use a table-based presentation and I want to use a accordion technique to fold rows in my table. My javascript is loaded and the click listener works as intended. But my css file is completely ignored. When I inspect the page in chrome the css classes are not loaded at all. I tried some easy things like

```
.test-table{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

and nothing is showing up.

How do I have to define my css class for using it in a report? I was surprised to see that I can not add css or javascript to the report element itself. Or do I have an error in my code definition? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even the answer was not quite correct, the link @MrKumar posted showed me the correct way. Apparently for CustomFields the approach using the method `requireResource()` is outdated and one should put these resources in `<context>atl.general</context>`. It worked directly with my reports too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

webResourceManager.requireResource("groupId.artifactid:web-resource").

Example from the below link:
webResourceManager.requireResource("com.avvd.jira.plugin.inquirer:inquirer-resources")

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Velocity-don-t-load-resource/qaq-p/489704

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use "-" in your context string, replace all the "-" with "."

```
<context>jira.reports.context</context>
```

and

```
$webResourceManager.requireResourcesForContext("jira.reports.context")
```